# systemd system to schedule daily reboot

Tags: systemd, snapcraft

I want to schedule a daily reboot on ubuntu core. There is no `cron` on ubuntu core.

But I can use `systemd` services

I have created a `reboot.service` and a `reboot.timer`

```
[Unit]
Description=reboot servuce
Requires=reboot.service

[Timer]
Unit=reboot.service
OnBootSec=2min
# every day at 4am
OnCalendar=*-*-* 4:00:00

[Install]
WantedBy=basic.target
```

But the problem this is executed on reboot. So there is reboot loop.

How do I avoid this.

I can write a reboot script that checks the last reboot time and only reboots if 24 hours has passed. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

From the man:

> Timer unit files must include a [Timer] section, which carries information about the timer it defines. The options specific to the [Timer] section of timer units are the following:
>
> OnActiveSec=, **OnBootSec=**, OnStartupSec=, OnUnitActiveSec=, OnUnitInactiveSec=

and further

> **OnCalendar=**
> Defines realtime (i.e. wallclock) timers with calendar event expressions. See systemd.time(7) for more information on the syntax of calendar event expressions. Otherwise, the semantics are similar to OnActiveSec= and related settings.
>
> Note that timers do not necessarily expire at the precise time configured >with this setting, as it is subject to the AccuracySec= setting below.
>
> May be specified more than once, in which case the timer unit will trigger **whenever any of the specified expressions elapse**. Moreover calendar timers and monotonic timers (see above) may be combined within the same timer unit.

Thus your timer triggers every time 2 minutes have passed after a boot, thus most probably causing what is experienced as a loop.